# Modify sqldatasource selected data before binding?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, datasource, sqldatasource

1. how can i access the my sqldatasource selected datasource for modification and adding for example new datacolumns  before binding??
2. where is the best place to perform these modifications ?
3. I guess SqlDataSource1_Selected is the right place, but i don't know how ?

----------updated---------

I found how to to access the selected data to show the total record but my questions is still not solved

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = ((DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)).Table;
        LabelTotal.Text = string.Format("{0} items found", dt.Rows.Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that doing this causes the SELECT command to run twice (in the usual databind and in your code to explicitly call it again) - which will be inefficient if the query is heavy.

Answer (score 2):

It will be better if you bind `GridView` using your custom code at .cs page rather than use SqlDataSource.

At .cs page you can perform your operation with `datatable` before bind `gridview`.

Comment: thanks , currently i am doing as you said in some more complicated pages and now i need that modifications for some simpler report pages that i use only sqldatasource and objectdatasources in a simple way